# Keep access log file in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have log file

> 88.191.254.20 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:00:32 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0"
>   66.249.66.231 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:06:20 +0100] "GET /popup.php?choix=-89 HTTP/1.1"
>   66.249.66.231 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:11:20 +0100] "GET /specialiste.php HTTP/1.1"
>   83.198.250.175 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:40:06 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 
>   83.198.250.175 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:40:06 +0100] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1"
>   83.198.250.175 - - [22/Mar/2009:07:40:06 +0100] "GET /images/ht1.gif HTTP/1.1"
>  .....

I want the result like this
**result**

> "88.191.254.20", 1 times,
>  "22/Mar/2009", "07:00:32", "+0100", "GET
>   / HTTP/1.0"
>
> "66.249.66.231", 2 times,
>  "22/Mar/2009", "07:06:20", "+0100", "GET
>   /popup.php?choix=-89 HTTP/1.1"
>  "22/Mar/2009", "07:11:20", "+0100",
>   "GET /specialiste.php HTTP/1.1"
>
> "83.198.250.175", 3 times,
>  "22/Mar/2009", "07:40:06", "+0100",
>   "GET / HTTP/1.1"
>  "22/Mar/2009", "07:40:06", "+0100", "GET
>   /style.css HTTP/1.1"
>  "22/Mar/2009", "07:40:06", "+0100", "GET
>   /images/ht1.gif HTTP/1.1

and save result in csv file

Comment: Did you try modifying the formatter? 
Something Like - dbg_fmt  = "%(asctime)s , %(levelname)s , %(message)s"

Comment: @Vinay's solution probably best: change the output format at it's source. You can still use a regex, if you want a kind of solution you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one way to do it:

```
import re

aggregate = {}

conf = '$ip - $user [$date:$time $milis] "$request"'
regex = ''.join(
    '(?P<' + g + '>.*?)' if g else re.escape(c)
    for g, c in re.findall(r'\$(\w+)|(.)', conf))


with open('example.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(regex, line.strip())
        d = m.groupdict()
        if not aggregate.get(d['ip']):
            aggregate[d['ip']] = []
        aggregate[d['ip']].append((d['date'], d['time'], d['milis'], d['request']))

with open('out.log', 'w') as out:
    for key in aggregate:
        out.write('"{0}", {1} times,\n'.format(key, len(aggregate[key])))
        for item in aggregate[key]:
            out.write('"{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}"\n'.format(*item))
        out.write('\n')
```